# Adding a Class and Setting States Within The Same Function In React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function in React in which I'm trying to change the state and add a class that styles the clicked button. The problem is that when I avoid altering the state in the `userAnswers()` function the style does work, but when I add `setChoices()` the style doesn't work. This is the code:

```
function userAnswers (e) {
    
    const choiceBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".choice-btns")
    choiceBtns.forEach((btn) => {
        if (e.target.id === btn.id) {
            btn.classList.remove("chosen")
        }
    })
    e.target.classList.add("chosen")
    
    setChoices((prev) => {
        return prev.map((q) => {
            return {...q, [e.target.value]: false}
        })
    })
    
    setChoices((prev) => {
        return prev.map((q) => {
            if (q.id === e.target.id) {
                return {...q, [e.target.value]: true}
            } else {
                return {...q}
            }
        })
    })
    
}
```

I don't know I'm missing something here! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should only be setting the state in your function. Style changes should be handled within the component *based on* state.

Comment: @pilchard Yes got it. I thought I could do both in the same function. Thanks